# Pattern for input to allow multiple hashtags, divided by whitespace (#one #two)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Please help me to define a pattern for pattern attribute of input element (`<input pattern="myPattern">`) which allows to type one or more hashtags, divided by space.
For example:

```
#first //valid
#Second #and-3rd //valid
#one#two //invalid
```

I tried `(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)`, but it works only for one tag in input. How can I enhance it to allow multiple tags?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `^(#[a-z\d-]+\s?)+$`

Comment: jcubic, thanks a lot! it works :)

Comment: jcubic, but it allows to type #one#two, which is invalid. How to require a space between tags? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to allow for words starting with `#` and separated by space:

```
^#[\w-]+(?:\s+#[\w-]+)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ut2LHt/5)

**RegEx Description:**

```
^           # Start
#           # match literal #
[\w-]+      # match 1 or more word chars or hyphen
(?:         # start non-capturing group
   \s+      # match 1 or more whitespace
   #        # match literal #
   [\w-]+   # match 1 or more word chars or hyphen
)*          # end of capturing group. * makes this group match 0 more times
$           # End
```

**PS:** Note that anchors `^` and `$` are not needed when reges is used in `input` pattern.